# Can mmap on Mac return null?

Tags: linux, macos, null, posix, mmap

Both the [Linux manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html#NOTES) and the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) specify that, so long as the `MAP_FIXED` flag isn't provided, `mmap` is guaranteed to not return memory starting at address 0. However, no such guarantee is documented in the Mac `mmap` manpage.

I'm not sure how strict Mac's compliance with POSIX is. Does its `mmap` provide this guarantee?

Comment: I think you can safely assume that `mmap` on Mac won't return an address starting with `0`. Doing so would break a great many things.

Comment: Anything goes. It can, however, return -1 (cast to a void pointer) to indicate failure.

Comment: @KevinBallard I agree, but I'd like a guarantee a bit stronger than that - ideally documentation somewhere or at least a comment in the Darwin source code or something.

Comment: @wildplasser Does "anything goes" mean it can return NULL? What are you basing that on?

Comment: It can return NULL. But it wont.

Comment: ...so it can't? What I mean to say is, if I don't pass the `MAP_FIXED` flag, am I guaranteed that the return value will not be 0? "It can return NULL" implies to me that I am not given that guarantee, but "But it won't" implies that I am given that guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

macOS is POSIX-compliant. In fact, it's [certified as officially UNIX-compliant](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1490), which implies POSIX compliance.

In addition, from macOS's man page for the linker, `ld`:

```
 -pagezero_size size
             By default the linker creates an unreadable segment starting
             at address zero named __PAGEZERO.  Its existence will cause a
             bus error if a NULL pointer is dereferenced.  [...]
             By default on 32-bit architectures the page zero size
             is 4KB.  On 64-bit architectures, the default size is 4GB.
             [...]
```

Therefore, unless you did something really unusual to disable it, there's already one or more pages reserved starting at address 0. So, `mmap()` won't allocate new pages there.